# Attempting to display the same data from JSON's multiple rows

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I'm having issue trying to display the header consisting of multiple results using jQuery and JSON using Open Layer web mapping technology. The data is being imported using import.sql and PostgreSQL.

Original Data:

2016-02-20,Mexico-Baja_California,state,weekly_zika_confirmed,MX0001,NA,NA,0,cases,POINT(-113.41426 27.808935)

2016-02-20,Mexico-Baja_California,state,yearly_cumulative_female,MX0002,NA,NA,0,cases,POINT(-113.41426 27.808935)

2016-02-20,Mexico-Baja_California,state,yearly_cumulative_male,MX0003,NA,NA,0,cases,POINT(-113.41426 27.808935)

The expected display should look like below:

Mexico-Baja California

- weekly_zika_confirmed
- zika_confirmed_male
- zika_confirmed_female

Instead of showing, currently, looking like:

Mexico-Baja California

- weekly_zika_confirmed

Mexico-Baja California

- zika_confirmed_male

and so on.

The code snippet, using the .append method, I have so far:

```
map.on('click', function(event) {
    $('.sidepanel-reports').empty();
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature,layer) {
        console.log(feature); // ignore this part - for analysis purposes only

        $('.sidepanel-reports').append(`
            <h3>${feature.get('location')}</h3>
            <li>
                <p>${feature.get('dataField')} : ${feature.get('value')} ${feature.get('unit')}</p>
            </li>`
        );
    });
});
```

I know that this code doesn't look right - I just cannot limit to one data (location). The behavior should be the same as found in SQL's SELECTIVE DISTINCT to select just one data. With 1 data, it encompasses all results that falls under the header's category. If you know a better approach, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forEachFeatureAtPixel or getFeaturesAtPixel might return features in a random order, if you use getFeaturesAtPixel and sort the array you should be able to construct a grouped output.  The sorting and grouping could be extended to subheadings if necessary.

```
var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
features.sort(function(a, b){return a.get('location') < b.get('location') ? -1 : a.get('location') == b.get('location') ? 0 : 1)});
var location;
features.forEach( function(feature) {
    if (feature.get('location') !== location) {
        location = feature.get('location');
        $('.sidepanel-reports').append(`
            <h3>${feature.get('location')}</h3>
        );
    }
    $('.sidepanel-reports').append(`
        <li>
            <p>${feature.get('dataField')} : ${feature.get('value')} ${feature.get('unit')}</p>
        </li>`
    );
});
```

Comment: That worked, I did some modification to it. Thank you!